# Why does angular run so many compileNode?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After I call angular.bootstrap, it starts compiling the page. I am wondering normally how long does it take?

It takes around 1.4s on my modern mac laptop, and more than 8s on a samgsung android chrome.

I am on angular1.3/1.4, is there anything I can do to improve this startup compile time?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: It isn't possible for anyone to know why your code is behaving this way without *seeing* your code.  That screenshot doesn't have any meaningful information on it's own.

Comment: Do you do anything heavy in your custom directive's compile function?

Comment: Thx guys, I don't think I have any special heavy stuff in the compile fn. I don't even have compile function. Just generic speaking what could go wrong? it is just in the compile phase after all. I do use browserify-ng-html2js to include html as string and bundle them in the appTemplate cache

Comment: well it *looks like* you have some sort of loop where angular is calling `$digest`, and then as a result of the `$digest`, some new angular variables appear which is causing `$digest` to be run again, a few times at least.  but without seeing the code or the HTML, it's really only a guess.

Comment: its normal on typical angular 1, what you cab do is use less dom, less directives, and less nested one, or write own renderer which I chose that way.

Comment: thx @Claies, i'll recheck my code see if i can dig up anything.

Comment: Hi @YOU, do you have a public version of your renderer? I am just out of curiousity and want to learn.

Comment: @garyx, yes but it has very limited features - https://github.com/S-YOU/doTA, and this is the site I am using it - https://www.giveucar.com/, you can check performance in chrome profile or timeline. I am very much micro performance mania, but most people like 90%+ will never need it.